# jQuery append adding extra qoute

Tags: javascript, jquery

My Code:

```
$("#thescreenshots").append("<img class='screenshotthumbnails' 
    onclick='openScreenshotModal('"+dataReturned['screenshots'][i]+"')'
    src='/assets/screenshots/"+ dataReturned['screenshots'][i] +"'>");
```

Is outputting:

```
<img class="screenshotthumbnails" onclick="openScreenshotModal(" 'img_0203.png')'="" 
    src="/assets/screenshots/IMG_0203.PNG">
```

Why does it add an extra weird qoute? And how can I fix this?

Comment: What is the output that you expected, and how does it differ from what you actually got?

Comment: You see in the onclick it adds an extra qoute

Answer (score 2):

You need to escape some of your quotes. Try this:

```
$("#thescreenshots").append('<img class="screenshotthumbnails" onclick="openScreenshotModal(\''+dataReturned['screenshots'][i]+'\')" src="/assets/screenshots/'+ dataReturned['screenshots'][i] +'">');
```

It will output something like this:

`<img class="screenshotthumbnails" onclick="openScreenshotModal('img_0203.png')" src="/assets/screenshots/IMG_0203.PNG">`

Answer (score 1):

Use double quotes inside thee click event after escaping

```
onclick='openScreenshotModal(\"" + dataReturned['screenshots'][i] + "\")'
```

This makes sure, that the property does not end abruptly as the outlying property starts with a single quote.

Answer (score 0):

It would be better to separate the javascript from the HTML - form & function and all that...

Try something like this:

```
$('body').on('click', '.screenshotthumbnails', function(){
  var largeImage = $(this).attr('data-larger-image');
  openScreenshotModal( largeImage );
});

var image = '<img class="screenshotthumbnails" data-larger-image="img_0203.png" src="/assets/screenshots/IMG_0203.PNG">';

$("#thescreenshots").append( image );
```